# Is there a formal Apache Parquet specification?

Tags: parquet, specifications

I am in the process of understanding the Parquet File Format and there doesn't appear to be a formal specification for this. As an example, what is the layout for the metadata?  What I do see is a lot of code implementations.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Marc

Answer (score 10):

The Apache Parquet format has a formal specification which resides at https://github.com/apache/parquet-format. Changes are either discussed in the form of a pull request or if they are larger on the mailing list of the Apache Parquet project https://parquet.apache.org/community/.